# Resizing <img> causing slowness

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am working on a site that will have a lot of images inside of boxes (divs) sorted as a grid (absolute positioning). I have noticed that resizing the images to fit the boxes causes the site to slow down significantly. There are a lot of images (342), but I don't understand why this is the case as the site runs quickly when I don't resize them.

Please note: I plan on implementing the dynamic resizing of the boxes in the future. **I mention this to avoid the answer of saving every image at another size. I am interested in knowing the cause of the slowdown not a different method of implementation.**

The grid is initially made up of boxes (divs) that are 150px * 150px. The grid is in the `<body>` and initially has no images (just empty divs). When the body has loaded, a JavaScript function places the images into their appropriate box. The JavaScript function relies on PHP for getting the images from a database as well as for resizing. Here are the steps for that section of PHP:

1.) PHP gets image filename from database.

2.) PHP gets image dimensions (in pixels) and saves them into two variables. I'll call them x and y here.

3.) I change x and y so that the image will fit 150px * 150px (or whatever initial value I assign to the boxes' initial dimensions).

4.) I use `echo` to `write document.getElementById("PHP given Id").innerHTML = '<img src="PHP given filename" style="width:PHP x value; height:PHP y value"/>';`.

If I comment out step 3 in my code the site runs quickly (that is commenting out the part that changes x and y from the image default dimensions). I have also tried setting the width and height attributes of the `<img>` instead of inline CSS but that does not solve the slowness issue.

Comment: Modifying width / height will just resize the image manipulation on `DOM`. However, it wouldn't speed up your image things because all of your image is loading on `onload` and after that, you resize it. Try, image thumbnails or `php scripts` that dynamically modify the sizesz.

Comment: Well, the browser has to resize those images. If there is 342, it can take some time, more significantly on a slower machine and an older browser.

Comment: Why are you resizing the images with JS? Why not do it at the same time you generate the HTML?

Comment: @HamzaWaqas, I specifically wrote I will not save multiple image sizes. How would PHP dynamically resize an image? It runs once before the other languages.

Comment: @Mark, I tried that but I had the same issue with speed. It is useful to have it in JavaScript because changing the code to accept dynamic resizing later will not be difficult.

Comment: Look at your page loading using Chrome Dev Tools in the Timeline panel. If you see that most of the time is used in redrawing then you have to resize your images.

Comment: @asimes, Search for script like `PHP Thumbnails` or `Showpic.php`. I had the one, but missing it right now.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, could you explain a little bit more please? I had a hunch that some kind of transformation has to happen but I don't know about this. Even dragging the bottom right of the window to resize the window is slower when I don't comment out step 3.

Comment: @asimes: I figured the browser would have to render it twice if you use JS...once to render it at it's initial size, and again to resize it. You can still resize later with JS, just hopefully not every image all at once? Anyway, I don't think there's a workaround for this. Resizing that many images is just naturally slow; you're going to have to reduce the load somehow.

Comment: @asimes, try this script. https://github.com/ArkeologeN/ImageGenerator

Comment: @HamzaWaqas, PHP runs one time. I plan on being able to allow users to resize the grid as they please (many times). The images will be resized (using CSS) many times.

Comment: Make ajax calls on every resize to your page. The URL fragment will take `width` & `height` and then will generate, optimized image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resizing images takes quite a bit of computing power, hence the slowdown. Best thing you could do is resize images with PHP and save thumbnails, so you only do it once.

Comment: I'd like to quote the OP here, "I mention this to avoid the answer of saving every image at another size"

Comment: It's the only real solution. The images have to be resized and it doesn't matter if it happens client side or server side - either way it will be unacceptably slow, no matter what you do.

Comment: OP could lower the resolution of each image.

Comment: @RobertSmith: That's what I do on my site actually. I've saved the images as a few different resolutions and I just pick the best fit one, then stretch it a tiny bit with HTML/CSS.

Comment: Lowering the resolution would speed it up a bit, but I'd rather avoid it if only for the reason IE6 and IE7 will use nearest neighbor for HTML/CSS resize and the end result is simply terrible.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I had the same issue a while ago but it didn't have to do with javascript.

Comment: I wish they just died already, but they refuse to. Total market share is still over 1% and I for example aren't willing to tell potential customers to f... off just because they refuse to upgrade their browser. In some regions (China for example) IE6 has a third of the market (which is yet another proof of human rights violations there :P )

Comment: Even though the image size (in bytes) has not changed, resizing it (dimensions) still causes this computing power slowdown right? I actually do not have to show every image at once, only as many as fit the current width / height of the window of the user. The other images are just off the screen. Maybe I'll let images off the screen be at their normal dimensions to see if this solves the problem.

Comment: @c2h5oh Haha, right. I understand. In this case, we don't know if the OP needs to have such a wide range of browsers.

Comment: @asimes If you can change the resolution of your images, obviously browsers won't be so slow in rendering them. Another option would be to use ajax to load some images as the user scrolls down.

Comment: @asimes How about you create multiple sizes for each image and save them serverside and just crop them in DOM if the size difference doesn't exceed 10% (div background instead of img) ? You won't be saving every single resolution possible and have a decent performance

Comment: No scrolling actually. I'll just post the site so far (it is a WIP): http://snorky2.evl.uic.edu/Alex/gBoxes_WIP_2.php

Comment: @asimes: You don't have to leave the images at their normal resolution... remove them completely or put empty `<divs>` in their place. Dynamically load them in as the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: Actually, your images are not so heavy as I thought but lowering resolution would help. Furthermore, you're making a lot of requests. If you can, use a sprite to reduce all those requests to a single one. Finally, can you get rid of javascript? What about using plain simple width: 100%; max-width: 100% to fit every image in its parent container?

Answer (score 0):

use `gd` library in php to load image dynamically and resize it, then use `header` function in php to tell browser that you are sending an image (not text). the you output resized image.

with this approach, you could use something like this for `<img>` tags:

```
    <img src="script.php?file=someFile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
```

with this, you dont need to create thumbnail for each image.